# Use FlaskForm and wtforms to create form with variable number of fields

Tags: html, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Using FlaskForm and wtforms, how would you design a form to contain base fields like name and age but also have a variable number of question fields based on a preset integer that changes from one form generation to the next?